# Mounting with cronjob creates duplicate mounts?

Tags: mount, cron

I have a mount using this command

`mount -t cifs -o username=xxx password = xxx //server_address //data_directory`

Unfortunately this mount often breaks because of IT server maintenance, and I have to re-mount it. I've decided to simply redo the mount daily on a cronjob, with the command above.

The mount still works, but when I run `findmnt`, it looks like I have 10 mounts for my directory all nested under each other. Has anyone ever run into this?

How can I either "overwrite" my mount or only run the mount command if the mount does not currently exist?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`umount /path/to/data_directory`
and `mount` again

or

just add `-o remount` to your mount command

Answer (score 1):

Use the automounter. Set it so that when you're not using the mount it gets automatically unmounted, and as soon as you want to use it again it gets (transparently) mounted once more.

Couple this with the `deadtime` on the remote server and you should be good to go.

---

There is a `systemd` automounter but I've not used that. Here's what I have had running on a couple of my own systems.

1. In `/etc/auto.master`

   ```
   /var/autofs/misc    /etc/auto.misc    --timeout 600
   ```

   Then `mkdir /var/autofs/misc` as a one-off operation
2. In `/etc/auto.misc`

   ```
   rShare -fstype=cifs,credentials=/usr/local/etc/cifs.secret,noperm,vers=3.0,iocharset=utf8      ://remoteServer/remoteShare
   ```

   Then put your credentials into the root-owned file `/usr/local/etc/cifs.secret` and ensure it's also readable only by root

   ```
   chown root.root /usr/local/etc/cifs.secret
   chmod 600 /usr/local/etc/cifs.secret
   ```
3. Finally, symlink the directory `/var/autofs/misc/rShare` to the real place in the filesystem you want to access it from. For example if you usually use `/path/to/data` then you would use this

   ```
   cd /path/to                                # Parent of old mountpoint
   rmdir data                                 # Delete old directory
   ln -s /var/autofs/misc/rShare data    # Symlink from autofs
   ```

From now on when you reference a file or directory at or in `/path/to/data` the mount will be activated on demand. After 10 minutes (600 seconds) idle time it will be automatically unmounted. All transparently.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's mounted before mounting it again.  Running `mount` with no args gives you a list of the current mount points, which you can pipe into grep.

e.g. with `grep`:

```
if ! mount | grep -q //data_directory ; then
  mount -t cifs -o username=xxx password = xxx //server_address //data_directory
fi
```

This can be shortened to just one line:

```
mount | grep -q //data_directory || mount -t cifs -o username=xxx password = xxx //server_address //data_directory
```

---

You could also use `awk`, to do an exact match on field 3 of `mount`'s output (`grep` will just test if the search string appears anywhere in a line, which is mostly good enough but not perfect):

```
if ! mount | awk -v ec=1 '$3 == "//data_directory" {ec=0; last}; END {exit ec}' ; then
...
fi
```

(this requires GNU awk or mawk or any other version of awk that understands the `last` statement)

---

BTW, checking if a filesystem is mounted is especially useful in an `rsync` or similar backup script if the target directory is supposed to be a separately-mounted partition or network mount.  You want the backup script to print an error message and abort if the target isn't mounted, otherwise the backup will just use up space on the wrong filesystem (and probably not be noticed later because it'll be hidden behind the mount-point when the target dir IS correctly mounted).

(how do i know this? because I've made the mistake of writing backup scripts that DON'T check before running rsync or whatever...and filled up my root filesystem with a copy of itself)